# Trouble running a Java application on localhost

Tags: java, localhost

EDIT: Port 135 seems to work. Sorta. It doesnt seem to refuse the connection and it lets me write things in the console, although nothing happens when i change the line. I will try more things

I am trying to run this:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MainProgram {

    private static String host;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        host = "localhost";

        for (int i = 1; i < 10001 ; i++)
        {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(host , i);
            }catch (UnknownHostException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But the output is always Connection Refused. Here is part of the output:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any way to fix this? My Debug Configurations for the remote java application look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbm0l.png

I have WAMP server installed, maybe I should use it? I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your local ip address rather then using "local" 
Use "cmd> ipconfig" to locate what your ip address for localhost, and then add it like this as following:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MainProgram {

private static String host;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    host = "192.168.0.13";

    for (int i = 1; i < 10001 ; i++)
    {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(host , i);
        }catch (UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Remember that this is my ip for local host! Your can be something else.

Comment: This should not be necessary assuming the DNS lookup for `localhost` be working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no serversocket listening in your localhost.  You need to run a server socket to listen the port which will be connected by client. For example:

```
Server Socket:
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    enter code here

package com.jdbc.test.net;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      Socket socket=null;
      BufferedReader br=null;
      PrintWriter pw=null;
      try {

       ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(3081);
       while(true){
        socket=server.accept();
        System.out.println("server:"+socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
       }

      } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{

       try {
        pw.close();
        br.close();
        socket.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

     }
    }

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Cleint Socket:
`enter code here`
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
package com.jdbc.test;

import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;
public class MainProgram {

    private static String host;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        host = "localhost";

        //for (int i = 10000; i < 10001 ; i++)
        {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(host , 3081);
            }catch (UnknownHostException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any idea start reading this [Socket Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

I suggest you code you own server socket to listen connection from client code (something like the code you wrote).
Use high ports number, above 5000 to avoid reserved ports and other maybe used by your computer programs.